# Are automation events on nodes canceled on node disconnect?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm disconnecting audio nodes (`GainNode`, `StereoPannerNode`) and reusing them later in another situation at another time (to reduce GC activity). Should I cancel all automation events on AudioParams of the node (should I call for example [`node.gain.cancelScheduledValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/cancelScheduledValues)) or it's done automatically when calling [`node.disconnect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode/disconnect)?

I didn't find any details in the documentation at MDN, so I assume the AudioParams may still be changing after a node is disconnected.

Comment: Didn't took the time to read it all, but have a look at the green note here: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorkletProcessor-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very good question.  Since the [WebAudio spec](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/) doesn't say, I think it's best to assume that the automations are still in place.  If you don't want that, you need to cancel any automations before you reconnect them.